# Retrieve get request on store() method

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, get, inertiajs

I have a query parameter on my URI `/posts?type=press`

I am getting on the `index()` method and passing it on to the view and everything is working as expected.

```
// Controller
public function index(Request $request)
    {
         $type = $request->get('type');
         return Inertia::render('Post', [
            'type' => $type
        ]);
    }

// Vue
<div class="types" v-if="$page.props.type === 'press'">
</div>
```

However, when I do the same thing on the `store()` method, it's not even recognizing `$type`
It recognizes `$request->input('inputText')` but not `$type`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
        $type = $request->get('type');

        if ($type === 'press') {
            return 'type press on submit';
        }

        if(empty($request->input('inputText'))) {
            return 'field must not be empty';
        }
}
```

Comment: Because store has POST method web route and can't read nothing from URI. Index supports GET method. why index works.

Comment: @MartinAmu is there any other way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Try change POST to GET in routes/web.php. But it's not safe if you want to send important data to the store function.

Comment: I am not conversant with Laravel, but surely the Request object has a way to get the POST data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I abandoned this approach and instead I passed the URI parameter from Vue/Inertia to the controller as part of the payload.

```
data() {
    return {
        form: {
            length: null,
            inputText: null,
            type: window.location.search.substring(6),
        }
    }
}
```

And in the controller

```
$type = $request->type;

if ($type === 'press') {
    return 'type press on submit';
}
```